# Htaccess redirect exclude subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, laravel

I have application in Laravel and also another folder in public_html that I want to exclude
from Laravel's redirection.

For example in public_html I have folder staff/

I want to exclude redirection for all files and folders in that folder so if someone tryes to access

domain.com/staff/index.php or domain.com/staff/folder1/ to actually looks into that directory.

For now my htaccess is like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Exclude directory from rewriting
RewriteRule ^(staff) - [L]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

This works for domain.com/staff it actually opens the index.php in staff/ instead of laravel index.php in root directory. but with this if I go to /staff/folder/ it uses Laravel.

How to exclude directory with all subfolders and files from laravel router?

Comment: You could add a route to staff with a custom filter that always returns false :P. Or if you want to exclude only the subfolders add a route for staff/{whatever} with the false custom filter

Comment: Is there an htaccess file in the `staff` directory?

Comment: That's interesting. The `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` and `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` should already prevent redirecting into Laravel if that file/folder already exists, no?

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expression to match requests that matches exactly `staff` or starts with `staff/`, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^staff($|/) - [L]
```